# Why does the first Unit Test take much longer

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I have got a very simple project that i just started to write to sketch some use cases. As of now it contains just some interfaces and mocked classes with static return values.
Then i wrote a couple of super simple unit tests for the beginning that just call one method and check the return value.
The whole project contains like 5 files with 25 lines each and I have got a total of 100 lines of code for the tests.

Now I can observe that the first test takes an additional 45ms probably for loading the assembly or something. I searched a lot but I could only find articles about all tests being super slow. As the performance of the new module will be super important, we were going to analyze the execution times of the tests, to see if any method suddenly takes longer than before. If we use multiple test runners for parallel testing these 45ms added to random tests will kill our analysis.

There are probably a lot of articles about this behavior already, so would appreciate if anyone could help me find them.

Comment: "As the performance of the new module will be super important, we were going to analyze the execution times of the tests, to see if any method suddenly takes longer than before." So do that using proper benchmarking tools (e.g. BenchmarkDotNet) - don't try to use unit tests for both correctness testing and performance measurements.

Comment: We're going to do proper benchmarking on a higher level that will be executed daily, but the unit tests are being executed for every commit so we would get the data on a more detailed level. We don't need this for any SLA or something, just to find the "bad commit" faster.

Comment: But using unit tests to measure performance is *inherently* problematic because it's not designed for that purpose - you get exactly the kind of effect you're talking about. It would be better to have a small set of performance tests that are run on every commit as well, rather than trying to make the unit tests serve two purposes.

Comment: Effectively, you're saying "Why aren't unit tests giving reliable performance information?" and the answer is "Because they're not designed to do that."

Comment: I can absolutely understand your point, but I try to prevent our management to do something stupid like "why don't we just measure it ourselves at the beginning and end of each test. That is just 5 lines of code for copy and paste".

Comment: Well it's your job as a responsible engineer to tell management that it's a bad idea to use one tool (a unit test framework) for a job that it wasn't designed for, when there's another tool (the benchmarking framework) that *was* designed for it. You might want to point out that it's entirely reasonable for a unit test to do significant work validating the results, which would further skew the data.

Comment: It is not like I don't agree, but management is not actually known for decisions based on facts.

Comment: So you need to convince them. That's still your job, I'm afraid. Ignoring reality and using unit tests for the wrong purpose isn't the solution.